# Need to use jQuery to populate Contact Form 7 form field using Wordpress Custom Field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I don't know javascript so a little help here would be much appreciated.

I've got a Contact Form 7 form in the footer of my post:
http://aif.design/listing/71-barker-ave

There is a custom field in the post to receive an e-mail address ( for listing agent ).

I would like the Contact Form 7 form to send the form submission to that e-mail address.

I've tried using Contact Form 7 - Dynamic Text Extension plugin but the 'to' field in Contact Form 7 only works with an `[e-mail*]` field which can't pull the custom field.

I've got this field at the bottom of the form which is hidden from view:

```
[email* to-email id:to class:d-none]
```

I figure I need to populate the form id="to" using the custom field output from

```
[acf field="user_email"]
```

However, I don't know how to do this with javascript or jQuery.

Help Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this using jQuery:

```js
$("input[name='your-email']").on("change", function() {
  let email = $(this).val();
  $("#to").val(email);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your Email *"></span>
</div>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap to-email"><input type="email" name="to-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email d-none" id="to" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></span></p>
```

Comment: @ArtinFlight Glad that I was able to help :)